# Android Chromecast integration without mediaroutebutton

Tags: android, kotlin, chromecast

I am creating an app without appbar and toolbar, where i don't want to inflate the menu xml.

I require the casting to integrate the app. So any help. Most using the menu inflation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.